# Getting started with Windows Developement w/ 3D Graphics?

Tags: windows, 3d, directx

I am looking for book titles or other resources for showing me how to get started and become advanced at windows based software with 3d graphics.

Comment: Are you stuck on DirectX, or would you consider OpenGL as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on the application. A modeling application (Maya, Rhino) works differently from a game engine (Unreal, Crysis), a renderer (RenderMan, VRay) or a specialized tool such as Z-Brush. The math basics are the same, but data structures largely depend on the application.

If you just want to get some 3d graphics on the screen, go for [XNA](http://creators.xna.com/). It's focused on games, but it should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

I used to read a [book about beginning DirectX](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1598633619), i didn't finish it but it looked interesting and easy to follow. Also if you'll want to use a developed game engine, instead of creating your own, you can have a look at [Ogre](http://www.ogre3d.org/), it's free, open source and it has a lot of tutorials and examples, with a huge community behind. If you want something more simple and to use .Net you can have a look at [Microsoft XNA](http://creators.xna.com/en-US/).